# String concatenation in angularjs with ionic app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, string-interpolation

I'm new to both angular js & ionic. I'm using https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-datepicker Datepicker for one fo my android app. Currently, stuck one point.

What I need is dynamically build the datepicker on the page from data obj. In simple case I know how to use the Datepicker but,  at the time of dynamic generation of Datepicker, I don't know how to do.

In normal case following ionic datepicker directive code, I'm using & it's working fine.

```
<ionic-datepicker input-obj="datepickerObject">
    <button class="button icon-left ion-calendar"> {{datepickerObject.inputDate | date:datepickerObject.dateFormat}}</button>
</ionic-datepicker>
```

But, in case of dynamic generation, it needs to be something like this -

```
// For Start_Date
<ionic-datepicker input-obj="'datepickerObject_Start_Date">
    <button class="button icon-left ion-calendar">
        {{datepickerObject_Start_Date.inputDate | date:datepickerObject_Start_Date.dateFormat}}
    </button>
</ionic-datepicker>

// For End_Date
<ionic-datepicker input-obj="'datepickerObject_End_Date">
    <button class="button icon-left ion-calendar">
        {{datepickerObject_End_Date.inputDate | date:datepickerObject_End_Date.dateFormat}}
    </button>
</ionic-datepicker>
```

I'm getting those Start_Date & End_Date in "fieldRowKey" javascript variable. But, I can't able to understand how to concate that in run time.

```
Ex -
"'datepickerObject_'+fieldRowKey" 
OR 
"{{'datepickerObject_'fieldRowKey}}"
```

I know it's just matter of string concatenation and I tried in lot many way but, not getting teh right way to do.

Need some guidance.

Thanks

**Code updated**

Rather than, making manipulation in string I've made a controller function which will do the same thing & return back the require string. Here is the code -

```
<ionic-datepicker input-obj="getDatePickerObj(fieldRowKey)">
    <button class="button icon-left ion-calendar">
        {{getDatePickerObj(fieldRowKey).inputDate | date:getDatePickerObj(fieldRowKey).dateFormat}}
    </button>
</ionic-datepicker>
```

Controller function is -

```
// Method for creating datepicker obj string
$scope.getDatePickerObj = function(datePickerName){
    var datePickerObjStr = 'datepickerObject_'+datePickerName;
    console.log('datePickerObjStr : '+datePickerObjStr);

    return datePickerObjStr;
}
```

But, Still no luck  -.-

Got it. I was doing wrong in the `getDatePickerObj()` function. Here is the updated version.

```
// Method for creating datepicker obj string
$scope.getDatePickerObj = function(datePickerName){
    var datePickerObjStr = 'datepickerObject_'+datePickerName;
    console.log('datePickerObjStr : '+datePickerObjStr);

    return $scope[datePickerObjStr];
}
```

It's working fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going down the wrong path by trying to concatenate the variable names at run time.

I'm not exactly clear what exactly you're trying to do, but hopefully the following will point you in the right direction:

In your controller:

```
$scope.getDate = function(fieldRowKey) {
    return ...; //return the corresponding date object
};
```

And in your html:

```
<ionic-datepicker input-obj="getDate(fieldRowKey)">
```

Comment: @AndyHaslt - Thanks for the quick response. I updated my Directive like this...

```<ionic-datepicker input-obj="getDatePickerObj(fieldRowKey)">
         <button class="button icon-left ion-calendar">
          {{getDatePickerObj(fieldRowKey).inputDate | date:getDatePickerObj(fieldRowKey).dateFormat}}
         </button>
        </ionic-datepicker>```
But, don't still something is broken somewhere & ut's not working.

Comment: Also, created following function in Controller file - 

```$scope.getDatePickerObj = function(datePickerName){
        var datePickerObjStr = 'datepickerObject_'+datePickerName;
        console.log('datePickerObjStr : '+datePickerObjStr);
        return datePickerObjStr;
    }```

Comment: @mi6 could you please edit your question instead of posting code in the comment.

Comment: @AndyHaslt - Got the solution. updated the function ```getDatePickerObj()``` . Now it's working. Thanks for showing the right way to solve the problem.

Comment: @mi6crazyheart I think your getDatePickerObj() should be returning an objetc, not a string. But if this answer works for you, please mark it as accepted so the question is considered "answered".